# Prevent the loading of subclass table rows in TPT inheritance on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, table-per-type

I have the following table hierarchy in my database which i map to an Entity Framework model (Database First) using the Table-Per-Type (TPT) inheritance pattern:

[image: TPT inheritance]

The mapping in the EF model is straightforward: `AssetContent` is a base abstract class while the other 2 are concrete subclasses.

The `AssetContent` table participates into a many-to-many relationship with another table which, to keep the picture clear, is omitted.

My question is, how do i build a Linq-to-Entities query to load the related `AssetContent` table using `Include()` such that the 2 'sub-tables' are not loaded at all? This is especially important for the `DatabaseAssetContent` table, whose `BinaryContent` field may be quite large and of no relevance to the issuer of the query i want to build. As far as i observed, Entity Framework automatically loads the entire hierarchy for a table, whether lazy loading is enabled or not, but i am interested in loading only the rows in the `AssetContent` table.

Is such a query possible using Linq-to-Entities (for Entity Framework 6)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, i moved the `AssetContent` table's fields (except the `Id`) into another, new table, called `AssetContentWithMetadata`, which has a 1-1 relationship to the `AssetContent` table. This way, the `AssetContent` table remains indeed a bit awkward, with a single field (the ID), but now i can load the metadata table alone, without burdening it with the contents as well.